# how to do a query based on a shifting schedule (day/mids/swings)

Tags: oracle

I need to pull the total number of tickets created per shift together with the running total. I have an existing query which I thought was correct but after checking, it seems that it is pulling the wrong numbers.

```
    SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DTTM,'Y'),'YYYY') as "DATE"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DTTM, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '14:00' AND '22:00' THEN TKTNUM ELSE NULL END) AS "DAYS"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DTTM, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '06:00' AND '14:00' THEN TKTNUM ELSE NULL END) AS "MIDS"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DTTM, 'HH24:MI') NOT BETWEEN '06:00' AND '22:00' THEN TKTNUM ELSE NULL END) AS "SWINGS"
    ,COUNT(TKTNUM) "TOTAL"
    ,SUM(COUNT(TKTNUM)) OVER (ORDER BY (TRUNC(E.ESCDTTM,'Y'),'YYYY'))  -- c/o Littlefoot and Stew Ashton 
    FROM TKTCHISTORY 
    GROUP BY TRUNC(E.ESCDTTM,'Y')
    ORDER BY TRUNC(E.ESCDTTM,'Y')

SAMPLE DATA:
TKTNUM  TKT_CREATED
INC0001 01/10/2019 1:00
INC0002 01/10/2019 23:00
INC0003 03/10/2019 5:00
INC0004 03/10/2019 9:20
INC0005 05/11/2019 15:00

DESIRED OUTPUT:
DATE        DAYS    MIDS    SWINGS  TOTAL   
2019-08-01  8       13      1       22      22
2019-08-02  19      5       3       27      49
2019-08-03  23      6       6       35      84
2019-08-04  7       9       13      29      113
2019-08-05  4       17      2       23      136
2019-08-06  10      5       16      31      167
2019-08-07  3       12      11      26      193
```

"SWINGS" would pull tickets between 00:00 and 06:00 or 22:00 and 24:00 on the same date. For example, a ticket was generated on 02-Nov 01:00... when I pull the report it would be counted on 02-Nov for SWINGS when it should be for the 01-Nov duty.

I've come up with something that would probably help with the logic but am not 100% sure.

```
    WITH Shift_Sched (shiftdate,shiftsched) as
    (   
        SELECT 
        --sysdate
        CASE 
                WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate,'MI'),'HH24:MI')  BETWEEN '06:00' AND '23:59' THEN TRUNC(sysdate,'DD') 
                WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate,'MI'),'HH24:MI')  BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:59' THEN TRUNC(sysdate -1,'DD')
        END as "SHIFT DATE",
        CASE 
                WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate,'MI'),'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '06:00' AND '14:00' THEN 'MIDS' 
                WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate,'MI'),'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '14:00' AND '22:00' THEN 'DAYS' 
                ELSE 'SWINGS'
        END as "SHIFT SCHED"
        FROM DUAL
    )
    SELECT shiftdate,shiftsched,COUNT(shiftsched)  
    FROM shift_sched
    GROUP by shiftdate,shiftsched
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help understanding your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you want days from 6 AM to 6 AM the next day. If so, you can substract 6 hours to `tkt_created`, truncate it to day, and group by that. The rest is just conditional aggregation.

```
select
    trunc(tkt_created - 6/24) "DATE",
    sum(case when extract(hour from tkt_created) between 6 and 13 then 1 end) days,
    sum(case when extract(hour from tkt_created) between 14 and 21 then 1 end) mids,
    sum(case 
        when extract(hour from tkt_created) between 22 and 23
            or extract(hour from tkt_created) between 0 and 5
        then 1 end
    ) swings,
    count(*) total
from tktchistory
group by trunc(tkt_created - 6/24)
order by "DATE"
```

Note: I used standard SQL `extract()` instead of `to_char()`, which is Oracle specific; apart from being standard, another advantage is that it returns an integer rather than a string.

This can also be phrased as:

```
select
    trunc(tkt_created - 6/24) "DATE",
    sum(case when extract(hour from (tkt_created) between 6 and 13 then 1 end) days,
    sum(case when extract(hour from tkt_created) between 14 and 21 then 1 end) mids,
    sum(case when extract(hour from (tkt_created - 6/24)) between 16 and 23 then 1 end) swings,
    count(*) total
from tktchistory
group by trunc(tkt_created - 6/24)
order by "DATE"
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to queries and programming so I was having a hard time seeing the logic for the swings part earlier. And yes, a full 24hr shift would be from 6AM-6AM the following day. :)

Comment: @rookie17768: does the query returns the correct results for your real data?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. The dbase is at the office but I tried to replace tkt_created with LOCALTIMESTAMP and changed the timings on my PC and it works. I am still looking at the query and trying to understand how it does it. Thanks again